# how to get values inside the node ussing XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
 <Value>
           <ntin>00300231145014
            <additionalDetails>
                                <detail name="reorderQuantity">10000</detail>
                                <detail name="SerialLength">12</detail>
                                <detail name="OriginalNtin"/>
                          </additionalDetails>
                    </ntin>
        </Value>
```

want to get value of ntin 00300231145014

Answer (score 1):

XSLT uses XPath as its expression language and in the data model shared by XSLT/XPath/XQuery the `ntin` element has as its first child node a text node with the string value `00300231145014`
, then the second child node is the `additionalDetails` element.

So you can select `/Value/ntin/text()[1]` to select that first text node child or also `/Value/ntin/node()[1]` in your example as the first child node of any type is that text node. However, the string value of that node will include the white space after the digits and before the `additionalDetails` element. Thus, if you only want the string with the digits you could use `normalize-space(/Value/ntin/text()[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simple X-Path in `xsl:value-of` to achieve desire output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Value/ntin[1]/text()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```